# Exclude some SSIDs from iCloud syncing or no iCloud sync on some SSID

Tags: icloud, wifi

I am looking for a solution (I am not sure that's possible) to prevent our gear (iPhones and Ipads) to iCloud sync over some SSIDs.

I fly for a living and we use EFBs (Electronic Flight Bags) based on iPad.

When we fly we need to be able to get emails (so connected to an SSID) but I would like to prevent iPads and iPhones to do iCloud syncs over the aircraft internet which costs a lot and slow the satellite internet down.

Could be done automatically by excluding the sync over one SSID (the aircraft's) so we are syncing anywhere else? I know this is possible by going to settings and turning of iCloud syncing but if this could be done the way I would like that would be great.

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

With a non-jailbroken iOS this is not possible for Wi-Fi connections.

For jailbroken devices there are some firewalls available to block apps even on Wi-Fi.

Comment: Thank you. the Ipads and Iphones fleet is company property so not Jail-broken and they cant be.